# Hide row in view if any field is empty

Tags: 7, views

I have a **Drupal 7 view** that uses **fields** as display type.

There are three fields, and I don't want to show the row if any one field is empty.

Currently, I am adding a filter for each of the three fields to achieve this. meaning if I have 20 fields, I would have to go for 20 filters.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

**P.S.** I can do this by overriding the row style output template file, and then add some custom php code. But I want to know is there an easier way using the views administration interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can add filter criteria corresponding to the field on which you want to hide 
the row .
Suppose you want to hide the row if content: body is empty then you can add filter criteria as Content:Body **not equal to**  "" (where value field should be left empty).
This will automatically hide the row if the specific field is empty
.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. If I have 20 fields, I will have to add 20 filters.