# 'Views Field' issue in NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR - Hide if empty not working

Tags: views, entities

'Hide if empty' configuration of views is not working properly as a result all the empty fields are showing.

Is there any work around to force fully hide empty fields in the views result (Page/block) neither using the configuration under 'No Results behaviour nor using views-php/block-php?

Comment: Hi Lalas, you are not asking a question. If this is a bug, please handle this in de module's issue queue. If you believe this is not a bug, please change your post so it becomes an answerable question.

Comment: I have edited the question for more clarity

Comment: Under Format>Fields>Settings, there's an extra option for "Hide Empty Fields".. It could help.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions does not give much information about your view, but if you want to hide the complete output of a row (when using a table) you can do this:

> You can add filter criteria corresponding to the field on which you
>   want to hide  the row . Suppose you want to hide the row if content:
>   body is empty then you can add filter criteria as Content:Body not
>   equal to "" (where value field should be left empty). This will
>   automatically hide the row if the specific field is empty .

source: [Hide row in view if any field is empty](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104075/hide-row-in-view-if-any-field-is-empty)